# Session Handling Issue(To update DB row) - Session closes along with browser

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, session-timeout

I am using a database to store user details including username and password. It also has a `Security_check` column which has "logged_out" as default.

Whenever a user logs in I modify the `Security_check` value to "logged_in" from the page where i validate user (servlet). Whenever the user hits the logout button I explicitly change `Security_check` to its default value.

But when the user closes their browser without logging out, then there is a big problem because the `Security_check` column value for that user is still "logged_in" and after that when that user tires to log-in they will get an error message stating that you are already logged in (because i check the `Security_check` before allowing any user to log-in, and in this case they are already logged in). So he can't log-in and also he can't log-out because the session got expired when he closed the browser. So what should I do?

Below is the code for HttpSessionListener class, which is not working:

```
package com.svc.session;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class Session_Invalidator implements HttpSessionListener
{
    public Session_Invalidator()
    {
        try    
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
        }
    }

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se)
    {
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)    
    {
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();
        String uName = session.getAttribute("userName").toString().trim();

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;

        try 
        {
            // i am using a space between the colon and odbc because if 
            // I don't it will be converted to smile, so ignore the space
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc: odbc:CMS","","");
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("update Users set security_check=default where     login_name=?");
            stmt.setString(1, uName);
            int no = stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch(Exception e) 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific and tell us, what exactly is not working. Did you debug your code? Is the method `sessionDestroyed()` called, when the session deactivates? Are there any exceptions? Does your database access code work, if you call it separately? Independently, I think it is not a good idea to forbid a relogin, if there was no explicit logout. Even if your automatic logout at session deactivation works, the user has to wait for automatic session timeout (usually 20 to 30 minutes).

Comment: all are working fine, but when i close the browser, db (also sessiondestroyed) is not calling. but it is calling after default session expire time as usual. but inbetween that time user unable to login(as security_check in db is logged_in), so how can i update soon after browser close / system sudden turn-off

Comment: This is normal behaviour. The server will never know if the user closes the browser or is only in the kitchen to get some coffee. So the server will hold the session open until timeout for the case the user comes back and continues his work. As a consequence the `sessionDestroyed()` method is always called at session timeout and not when the browser is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think you have two alternatives.

1. Choose a very short session timeout (like one or two minutes) and implement something like a ping from your webpages to your server with AJAX calls. So while the user browser is open and shows your webpage your server will always get a ping notification and remains the session open. If the user closes the browser your server session will get a timeout very soon. But there is still a short delay. The downside of this approach is that you will produce more traffic and you have to find an appropriate session timeout value. A too short value can cause a session timeout if there are some network delays. A too long value raises the time period in which the user is unable to relogin.
2. This is my favorite solution: Don't be so restricted to disallow a relogin at all. Don't store the logged in state in your database. If the user wants to relogin after closing the browser then a new server side session is created and the user gives login credentials and good is. The old session will be destroyed after timeout. This is the default behaviour if you use container based security. I recommend to use container based security (JAAS). Why do you want to disallow a relogin?

Here are some links regarding JAAS:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html
- http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2008/04/Journal200804.jsp#a6

Comment: i got it...why iam storing login details in db is to display "online users", based on that row iam able to dispaly online users..IS THERE ANY OTHER WAY TO DISPLAY ONLINE USERS EXATLY

Comment: You can hold a set with all online users (or an interger if you are  interested in the number of online users) in application scope and use your session listener to update that set/integer. But be carefull to synchronize the access to your global value. The simplest case would be to only count the active sessions. Maybe this is enough for your use case. If you want to know who is online you have to treat a relogin special. But the original problem cannot be solved. You will never know when a user closes the browser until session timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I had a workaround to solve this problem, it is to use a global object to store sessionId and user's id together, when session timeout, we can get sessionId from session destroyed event, then we can get user's id by sessionId.
Please view my blog : [Update DB's User status when Session timeout](http://blog.csdn.net/allen_jinjie/article/details/53289490)